# Matlab Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, matrix

Why am I getting this error? The matrices are absolutely of the same size:

```
L=rand(4,1000);
 for i=1:1000;
    A(i)=logzn(0.1,0.4,L(4,i));
    B(i)=logzn(0.3,0.7,L(4,i));
    C(i)=logzn(0.5,1.0,L(4,i));
end
F=(~A&B | ~B&C);
```

Here's the logzn function:

```
function [ y ] = logzn( aMin,aMax,x )
if ((aMin<=x)&&(aMax>=x)) 
    y=1;
else
    y=0;
end
```

Here's the error I get:
Error using  & 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: Are you certain that the error is coming from these lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means exactly what it says, that `A`, `B`, and `C` are not the same size. You can check it with:

```
isequal(size(A), size(B)) && isequal(size(A), size(C))
```

That being said, the code as you've posted it doesn't have any issues; however if the error is in fact coming from these lines of code, you must have initialized `A`, `B`, and `C` to be different sizes somewhere else in the script (or you potentially used the same variable names previously and didn't clear them). You will want to pre-allocate them before the loop to ensure they are the same size.

```
L = rand(4, 1000);
[A, B, C] = deal(zeros(size(L,2), 1));

for k = 1:size(L,2);
    A(k)=logzn(0.1,0.4,L(4,k));
    B(k)=logzn(0.3,0.7,L(4,k));
    C(k)=logzn(0.5,1.0,L(4,k));
end

F=(~A&B | ~B&C);
```